# I was trying to create a .CSV file from my pandas DataFrame but it gives me an error " function() argument 1 must be code, not str"

Tags: python, dataframe

"function() argument 1 must be code, not str - Getting this error while creating csv file.
But if we create xlsx file there is no error.

Code tried : file_name.to_csv('text.csv')"

Comment: Is your DataFrame called `file_name`?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the `DataFrame` you are trying to export as CSV or Excel is in series format. You can check that using `type(file_name)`.

If the `DataFrame` is in `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame` format, only then we can use `file_name.to_csv`.

Otherwise, if it's in text or string format, you can write the file to text file using write:

```
with open("test.txt", mode='w') as f:
  f.write(file_name)
f.close()
```

Comment: You do not need `f.close()` call

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that file_name is actually a DataFrame, not a string.

Refer to:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html